# Ruby on rails: variable number of input boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web

I'm working on an application where the user needs to be able to upload multiple files at once in a submission form. Ideally I'd start with, say, three file upload fields with an 'add additional files' button that dynamically adds input fields. I can do the Javascript to handle this of course, but how would I access this "array" of files within my controller?

I've looked at a few canned solutions, but they're much more flashy than what I need, and I don't need ajax uploading either - just a regular old submit is fine.

So, to summarize: what's the best way to access zero or many uploaded files in a rails application?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found what I was looking for via the 'nested_form' ruby gem.